# Blender Bug? .OBJ File Vertex Colors Misalign Under Various Conditions

Tags: vertex-colors, obj

I have found that Blender likes vertex colors to simply be an extension of the “v” line in .OBJ files, so I insert vertex colors into my .OBJ file by making a 6-element “v” instead of a 3- or 4- element “v”.
IE:

```
v -291.437500 19.875000 -420.062500 0.749020 0.874510 0.121569
v -305.187500 16.000000 -362.187500 0.749020 0.874510 0.121569
v -247.937500 18.000000 -362.187500 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
```

By definition this means that vertex colors are strongly associated with vertices.  IE it is not possible to have the correct vertices but incorrect vertex colors.  And yet there are at least 2 ways this happens in Blender 4.0: Referencing only a section of the v/vt/vn tables and by using “o”.

This image shows what happens when an “o” line is inserted between any 2 faces:
[image: Left is correct, right is misailgned.]

The vertex colors are correct near the start of the data and then somehow get misaligned, despite the impossibility of such an occurrence.

The same result occurs if I simply cut off the face data at a certain point in the file.  I open the .OBJ file in a text editor, go to my “g 7” set of faces, and remove them and all of the faces after that:
[image: It should not turn orange on the right.]

Where it becomes orange on the right is incorrect.
The modification did nothing more than remove faces.  The v/vt/vn tables were not modified, nor were the indexes into them modified.  I simply have a bunch of v/vt/vn values that are unreferenced, but that shouldn’t be a problem.  The vertices are in the correct locations still, with the correct normals, and although it is not shown the UV coordinates are correct as well, but the vertex colors are somehow now misaligned even though we have already established that they are strongly connected to the vertex positions, so it’s not supposed to be even be possible for them to be misaligned like this, especially only because some v/vt/vn values are unreferenced.

Is this a known Blender bug?  Is there a work-around?  Can I edit some .PY file myself to fix this?  Where is it?  Because there is no **scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/import_obj.py** on my system (**import_obj.py** does not exist on my machine).

Comment: I tried to make a test file but couldn't reproduce. The new OBJ importer (the one with vertex color support) is written in C++, not Python. If you think you've found a bug, you should report it (Help > Report a Bug) and include all the info needed to reproduce in the bug report.

Comment: Issue was filed at https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/117367.